# Time filter for jmeter report

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

Is there any way that we can find out average response time for last one hour from the script which performed for 3 hours??
Hi, so I have script which is timed to run for 3 hours. I want aggregate report to find out average response time. But I want response data from the last one hour run. I want to find pout the average response from the transactions which where performed in last hour of run. Is this possible and how?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the reporting system you're using:

1. If you're reading the [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) you can use [Filter Results Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FilterResultsTool/) to "cut" first 2 hours of the test execution like:

   ```
   FilterResults.bat --output-file last-hour-only.jtl --input-file original-test-results.jtl --start-offset 7200 --end-offset 10800
   ```

   in this case `last-hour-only.jtl` will contain only sample results collected between 2nd and 3rd hours of the test run

   Filter Results Tool can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)
2. If you're using [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) you can use `jmeter.reportgenerator.start_date` and `jmeter.reportgenerator.end_date` properties to set the time frame where the "interesting" part of results is.